# Internal working of sorting used by Comparable/Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, compare, comparator, comparable

I was going through the Comparable and Comparator interfaces used for sorting in Java.I understood the basics that how these are working.

What I'm interested about is their internal working i.e, how the sorting actually takes place internally.

I'm assuming that the positive,negative or the zero values returned by the compare/compareTo method would be passed as parameters to some another Sort method.

I need to know what that sort method is internally or which sorting is being used, Any article or Code would be helpful.

Comment: Which sorting? Did you read the Javadoc? What was not clear?

Comment: Sorting of what? `Comparator` and `Comparable` are just `interface`s, so their implementation can and most likely will vary between every class that implements said interface, just look at `String#compareTo` and `Integer#compareTo` in the JDK

Comment: are you looking for an algorithm that sorts may be?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which sorting method you call, but in general: It's an implementation detail of Java that is intentionally not exposed to the user.

Going by Oracle Java 8, I can see that sorting of primitives uses some evil combination of Dual-Pivot Quicksort, Mergesort and InsertionSort, depending on whether the array (at any point in the algorithm) is <386 elements, <47 elements and/or if it determines that it is (heuristically) 'nearly sorted'.

On the other hand sorting of objects uses Python's sort algorithm by Tim Peters, which uses mini-Timsort when the array at any point in the algorithm is <32, or Mergesort if the flag `java.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort` is true.

[edit] `Arrays.sort` is equal to `Collections.sort` if array of objects.

Comment: @ Mark Do you have any references to any of the source codes.

Comment: [Arrays.sort](https://zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/util/arrays.java#L-142), [Collections.sort](https://zgrepcode.com/java/oracle/jdk-8u181/java/util/collections.java#L-139)